# Exporting from Enterprise Guide to access database

Tags: ms-access, sas, enterprise-guide

i am attempting to export a sas dataset to an existing access database as a new table. i am using the Data copy files tool and have connected it to my Program.
i receive the following error: Target folder \filelocation\file.accdb does not exist or cannot be access on "NY52214"(computername).

i am using the following:

```
proc export data=WORK.DETAILS
dbms=accesscs
OUTTable="data"
replace;
DATABASE='\\filelocation\file.accdb';
RUN;
```

I have used a similar code to this to export to excel which works, so i am not sure what i am doing wrong. i am unable to utlize pc file server but everything i have searched indicates this should be working. i have tried different file locations, different versions of access. Can anyone tell me what i am missing please?

Comment: Please add the relevant information from the SAS log to the post.

Comment: what other relevant information is available/needed aside from the code being run and the error I received?

Comment: Your `proc export` is failing, or that succeeds but then the CopyFiles tool is giving you this error?

Comment: The proc export works in conjunction with the copy file tool. The proc sql code fails and says lot cant access the file location